# How to rename sheets of multiple excel as same name using R

Tags: r

I have multiple excel files having different names e.g USA.xlsx, India.xlsx etc. Each file has only one sheet. I want to rename the sheet of each file as Sheet 1.

Desired output USA.xlsx should have sheet 1, India.xlsx should have sheet 1 and so on. I have 1800 excel files. I know renameWorksheet(wb, sheet, newName) will work for one file. I have 1800 excel files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should get the job done:

```
library(openxlsx)
list.files(pattern = '.xlsx')
for(file in list.files(pattern = '.xlsx')){
    wb <- loadWorkbook(file, xlsxFile = NULL)
    names(wb)[1] <- 'Sheet1'
    saveWorkbook(wb, file, overwrite = TRUE)
}
```

Comment: Error in names(wb)[1] <- "Sheet1" : class 'workbook' has no 'names' slot

Comment: Try replacing `names(wb)[1] <- 'Sheet1'` with `renameWorksheet(wb, 1, "Sheet1")`

Comment: 1st this error came: Error in loadWorkbook(file, xlsxFile = NULL) : 
  unused argument (xlsxFile = NULL)  i removed xlsxFile = NULL and then run the code tthen the error is Error: could not find function "renameWorksheet"

Comment: do you have `library(openxlsx)` at the beginning of the code?

Comment: i runned openxlsx.. then this error came     Error: zipping up workbook failed. Please make sure Rtools is installed or a zip application is available to R.
         Try installr::install.rtools() on Windows. If the "Rtools\bin" directory does not appear in Sys.getenv("PATH") please add it to the system PATH 
         or set this within the R session with Sys.setenv("R_ZIPCMD" = "path/to/zip.exe")

Comment: We are getting there, so here is what you need to do: 1. download and install RTools from [link](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) 2.  The set the environment variable `Sys.setenv(R_ZIPCMD= "C:/SOMETHING_PATH/Rtools/bin/zip") ` change the path pointing to bin folder. 3. Restart R and you should be good to go :)